# Hibernate Validation 6.0 ListValueExtractor.extractValues seems to have poor performance with large lists

Tags: java, hibernate, bean-validation

I am using Hibernate Validation 6.x. I have a field in an object that I'm validating which contains a list, `List<@NotNull Double> doubles` for example. The issue I'm facing is that when the list is very large, the performance degradation is substantial. To investigate the issue I implemented the validation of list elements as a custom validator on the List, `@ValidDoubles List<Double> doubles`, using a stream to iterate over the elements, and achieved a ~65% performance improvement for that validator.

After profiling the application I can see that the majority of time is being spent in `ListValueExtractor.extractValues`, which can be found [here](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-validator/blob/master/engine/src/main/java/org/hibernate/validator/internal/engine/valueextraction/ListValueExtractor.java). I am hoping that someone could explain why this method seems to be so expensive and if there are any known workarounds.

An example Object:

```
public class myDataObject {

    private List<@NotNull Double> doubles // List which can contain thousands of values

    // Getters and Setters
}
```

**Update**

Upon further profiling and investigation I believe the issue is related to Hibernate keeping track of which beans have already been validated when performing cascading validation, in particular the use of `System.identityHashCode` when doing so ([Here is the code](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-validator/blob/7b3236402fdcd0c4a713535f37b61f14d42e1553/engine/src/main/java/org/hibernate/validator/internal/engine/validationcontext/AbstractValidationContext.java#L503)).

Looking at my profiler, I can see that 11.6% of CPU time is spent validating the input beans. Of that time, 11.3% of time is spent calling `System.identityHashCode`. Interestingly, it is the second child object where the time is being spent even though they contain relatively simple validations. I wonder if I have configured either the validator or beans wrongly as this seems to be very weird.

My Validator configuration looks like so:

```
<bean id="validator" class="org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean">
         <property name="validationPropertyMap">
             <util:map>
                 <entry key="hibernate.validator.fail_fast" value="true"/>
             </util:map>
         </property>
</bean>
```

Validator invocation:

```java
Set<ConstraintViolation<InputObject>> violations = validator.validate(input);
```

Example object structure

```java
public class InputObject {
    @NotNull
    String name;

    @Valid
    List<FirstChild> firstChildren; // on average 10 objects but can be up to very large

    // Getters and Setters
}

public class FirstChild {
    @SomeCustomValidator // Not important
    Integer someValue;

    // 3 to 4 further fields with simple validators

    @Valid
    List<SecondChild> secondChildren; // On average around 40 objects but can be very large

    // Getters and Setters
}

public class SecondChild {
    @NotBlank
    String foo;

    @NotBlank
    String bar;

    // Getters and Setters
}
```

In conclusion:

- From the profiler, the issue lies in the cascading validations found from the `@Valid` annotations on the lists.
- The issue appears to be with Hibernate keeping track of the which objects have already been validated when performing cascading validation.
- The profiler is showing `System.identityHashCode` as the method taking up the majority of time spent validating.

Is this an optimization issue with Hibernate or could I either configure my validator or input object structure in some way that would produce better performance?

Comment: Can you explain how slow was the performance? And here you found details about implementation https://beanvalidation.org/proposals/BVAL-508-appendix/ And take thousand of values as input and validate is not a good approach. And you can create a custom deserializer to validate in your own way also.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. When validating the same list with a custom field level validator, using a stream to iterate over each element, the stream implementation was ~65% more efficient. I may look into implementing my own custom deserializer if there is no more optimal default solution for my use case.

Comment: Tiggered `@NotNull` for every element maybe cause the problem I guess. You can write an annotation also for List check all values are not null.

Comment: Hi, I've posted an update in the main question with some further details. The issue doesn't appear to be any one validator but instead an efficiency bottleneck being faced when performing cascading validation. In particular it appears an inordinate amount of time is spent calling System.identityHashCode which occurs when Hibernate tries to track which objects it has already validated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tough one.

So the issue you see is that we create a `BeanGroupProcessedUnit` per list value so when you have plenty, it doesn't scale well.

You don't have the issue when moving things outside of the list as we only keep a processed unit for the whole list.

I'm not entirely sure there's an easy fix for this that doesn't break other use cases but we should at least check if we can improve the situation in the case you have.

That being said, I would appreciate if you could take the time to open an issue on our tracker https://hibernate.atlassian.net/projects/HV/issues with a reproducer based on https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-test-case-templates/tree/master/validator ? That would be helpful to start the process.

Comment: Thanks for replying, I've opened an issue on your issue tracker https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HV-1831 and created a PR reconstructing the DTO structure that triggers the performance degradation https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-test-case-templates/pull/44

Comment: I'm experiencing the exact same issue. What would help move this issue forward?

Comment: Why is it necessary to keep track of what has been validated in the first place? We use the validator for validating input arguments in rest controllers. I don't understand why there needs to be any tracking of already validated beans in this use case. For a list of 8000 of our DTO's it takes almost 10 seconds. When I forked the hibernate-validator repo and harcoded disableAlreadyValidatedBeanTracking = true in AbstractValidationContext , it absolutely flies and validates our list of 8000 DTO's in 300m

Comment: Because it's required by the spec to avoid infinite loops. We are working on disabling it when we can detect there are no cycles in the metadata. It should arrive soon.

Comment: FWIW, we have not forgotten this and we are still making progress on this one and we have an in-progress PR here: https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-validator/pull/1170 . Still some work to do but we made some good progress already.